# Get unique array of Classes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of objects:

```
@searches
```

It could return something like:

```
--- !ruby/object:Profile
attributes:
  id: 2
  name: Basti Stolzi
  username: paintdat
  website: ''
  biography: ''
  created_at: 2013-06-10 19:51:29.000000000 Z
  updated_at: 2013-06-15 10:10:17.000000000 Z
  user_id: 2

--- !ruby/object:Essential
attributes:
  id: 4
  description: ! '#paintdat'
  user_id: 1
  created_at: 2013-06-16 08:19:47.000000000 Z
  updated_at: 2013-06-16 08:19:47.000000000 Z
  photo_file_name: Unknown-1.jpeg
  photo_content_type: image/jpeg
  photo_file_size: 101221
  photo_updated_at: 2013-06-16 08:19:46.000000000 Z

--- !ruby/object:Essential
attributes:
  id: 3
  description: ! '@user_mention_2 well done! #paintdat'
  user_id: 1
  created_at: 2013-06-16 07:56:55.000000000 Z
  updated_at: 2013-06-16 08:00:24.000000000 Z
  photo_file_name: Unknown.jpeg
  photo_content_type: image/jpeg
  photo_file_size: 135822
  photo_updated_at: 2013-06-16 07:56:55.000000000 Z
```

Now I'd like to get an unique array of the classes within that array like:

```
--- !ruby/class 'Profile'

--- !ruby/class 'Essential'
```

It would be nice to do this without 2 loops. Hope somebody could help me out! <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you perform a map and unique enumerable operators to do this. Your code would be something like (depending on what is required to select the class from an individual element):

```
@searches.map{ |search| search.class }.uniq
```

For more info, check the documentation on [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html) and [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html)

**Edit:**

Note the above can be more succinctly using the `&` operator (which converts a symbol into a proc):

```
@searches.map(&:class).uniq
```

Comment: @AndreZimpel, if it works, you should consider accepting this answer as correct.

Comment: @zeantsoi Yep, I had to wait for 6 minutes.

Comment: You can shorten the code using `@searches.map(&:class).uniq`.

Comment: @toro2k Good point, I edited the original answer to include your suggestion.